# Word for ability to understand, analyse and judge things

Tags: vocabulary, translation, equivalence

Is there one specific word in English to describe one's ability to understand, analyse and judge things? I'm trying to find an equivalence for 悟性 in English. Thanks.

Comment: Mmmmm. I like it.  Perceptive.  Cognizant. Sagacious. Intuitive. Acuminous. Keen.

Comment: Discerning. Shrewd. Insightful. Astute.

Answer (score 1):

**Savvy** may be a definition close to what you refer.

Comment: Intelligent; smart; clever... time to consult a thesaurus!

Comment: Yes, the closest to what he is asking  I think. It refers to intelligence, ability to comprehend,  and most, shrewdness.

Comment: Yes. Ermanen has it.  Savvy is the only translation. Of course, when I plugged this into my Chinese thesaurus I also got "insight", "perceptivity" and "wit".  Those darn Asians don't know their own language, by god.  (That is 2 out of 4 for me, by the way--Savvy was in there, too)

Comment: By "it" I meant "悟性"; I actually do have a Chinese thesaurus, btw.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite word for this is 'perspicacity'.  But as others have noted, there is a wide range of synonyms here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**wisdom**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisdom) and [**sagacity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wisdom).

> **wisdom**: the natural habilitation to understand things that most other people cannot understand; knowledge of what is proper or reasonable : good sense of judgment.
>
> **sagacity**: acuteness of mental discernment and soundness of judgment.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to propound is found in the definition of **sapiency**:  [ability to apply knowledge or experience or understanding or common sense and insight](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/115915/sapience)